# Swift: avoid to force unwrap constant variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to avoid a force unwrap of global variables. How can I do that in this particular example:

```
let AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Comment: Why? The syntax is perfectly fine (except the capitalized variable name). If the application delegate class doesn't exist your app won't even launch.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to force-unwrap (which is fine here in this case), then use `if let`.

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    // Do something with appDelegate
}
```

But the force-unwrap is fine for this. You want the app to crash during development if you make a typo on the type of the app delegate. It will never fail at runtime unless you make a change to the code and ship it to Apple without at least running your app once.

Comment: But how you declare and initialize as global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Made this an extension so no copy paste anymore. This is as type safe as it gets since it only makes sense for the `AppDelegate` to implement `UIApplicationDelegate` and the one is always reachable via `UIApplication.shared.delegate`.

```
#if os(macOS)
import Cocoa
typealias ApplicationDelegate = NSApplicationDelegate
typealias Application = NSApplication
#else
import UIKit
typealias ApplicationDelegate = UIApplicationDelegate
typealias Application = UIApplication
#endif

public extension ApplicationDelegate {
    static var shared: Self {
        return Application.shared.delegate as! Self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the variable locally then:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {   
    //logic here
}
```

or

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
```

I don't think there is a way to use AppDelegate globally without using force casting.

**Edited**

To create a global variable, just declare it anywhere outside a class. For example:

```
var globalVariable = 1 

class Person { 
//logic here 
}
```

Comment: But how you declare and initialize as global variable?

Comment: Following your example in my viewcontroller I get this error `Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'globalVariable'`

Comment: A global variable does not belong to any class. As a result, you can't do something like `ViewController.globalVariable`. To access a global variable, just use it directly. 
If you are talking about class variable then declare it inside a class scope. i.e 
`class Person {`
`var name = "Jack"`
`}`